# try, except and logger Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, logging

I have this method in my code but I want to pass the error to my log and to erase the print(e).

```
def get_used(self, obj):
    try:
        return '<a href="%(url)s">%(name)s</a>' % {'url': reverse('org', kwargs={'organization': obj.organization.slug}), 'name': obj.organization.name}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return ''
```

I found this documentation about logging calls https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/ but really I'm not sure is the implementation is in this way.

```
def get_used(self, obj):
    try:
        return '<a href="%(url)s">%(name)s</a>' % {'url': reverse('org', kwargs={'organization': obj.organization.slug}), 'name': obj.organization.name}
    except Exception as e:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.exception(e)
        return ''
```

or another idea that is in my mind it's create ***logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)*** as global variable.

I'm some confused how to build the loggers and I need help to code this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line from your code gives you a handle to the logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Now you can log messages acoording to severity with different functions, e.g.:

```
logger.debug("Very detailed information")
logger.info("Rather important information")
logger.warning("A warning")
```

Whether this gets printed or not depends on your loglevel and what handlers you have. Have a look in the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

In your case, this should probably work:

```
    except Exception as e:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.warning(e)
        return ''
```